# Converting 2 sat formula into an implication graph.

Tags: computational-complexity, satisfiability

Both [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability) and my lecturer explained how the 2 satisfiability problem work. However, I am finding it really hard understanding how this formula:

```
xvy≡ ¬x-->y ≡ ¬y -->x
```

Then breaks down the following conjectures :

```
(¬x v y) & (¬y v z) & (¬z v w) & (¬w v ¬x) & 
(x v ¬y) & (y v ¬z) & (z v ¬w) & (w v x)
```

is converted to an implcation graph.

Heres my attempt:

```
 (¬x v y) = (¬y-->x)

          = (¬x-->y)
```

but this cannot be right, as they have diffrent truth tables:

```
(¬y-->x)
```

1 0 **0** 0

1 0   **1**  1

0 1   **1**   0

0 1   **1**   1

```
(¬ x-->y)
```

1 0 **0** 0

0 1 **1** 1

1 0 **0** 0

0 1 **1** 1

I understand once you have the conjectures converted to implication, how to construct the implication graph and find out if its not satisfiable (bad loops).

Could someone please explain clearly how to break down the conjectures to implications?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A disjunction $A \vee B$ is equivalent to $\neg A \rightarrow B$ and also to $\neg B \rightarrow A$. This holds generally, i.e. not only when A, B are variables.

Therefore, by applying the above on $A=\neg x$ and $B=y$, you can get: $\neg x \vee y \sim \neg \neg x \rightarrow y \sim x\rightarrow y$ and also $\neg x \vee y \sim \neg y \rightarrow \neg x$.
($\sim$ denotes equivalence of propositions)

Similarily for any other disjunction of two literals.

Comment: how does ¬x∨y∼¬y→¬x ?

Comment: As I wrote, $A \vee B \sim \neg B \rightarrow A$ (the intuitive reasoning of this fact is simple: Suppose that $A$ or $B$. Then, if it is not $B$, then it must be $A$.) Now, just write $A = \neg x$ and $B = y$. Then $A \vee B \sim \neg B \rightarrow A$ is $\neg x \vee y \sim \neg y \rightarrow \neg x$.